# Changed layouts throw runtime error

Tags: android, android-fragments, linphone

I have some problem. when I change any xml-file, I get error on  main layout initialization (I sure only about small layouts). For example, if I add one more field on the setup-wizard fragment, I got that error:

```
09-15 20:33:49.697: E/AndroidRuntime(3529): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-15 20:33:49.697: E/AndroidRuntime(3529): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.linphone/org.linphone.LinphoneActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #81: Error inflating class fragment
09-15 20:33:49.697: E/AndroidRuntime(3529):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
09-15 20:33:49.697: E/AndroidRuntime(3529):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
09-15 20:33:49.697: E/AndroidRuntime(3529):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
09-15 20:33:49.697: E/AndroidRuntime(3529):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
09-15 20:33:49.697: E/AndroidRuntime(3529):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-15 20:33:49.697: E/AndroidRuntime(3529):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
09-15 20:33:49.697: E/AndroidRuntime(3529):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
09-15 20:33:49.697: E/AndroidRuntime(3529):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-15 20:33:49.697: E/AndroidRuntime(3529):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-15 20:33:49.697: E/AndroidRuntime(3529):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
09-15 20:33:49.697: E/AndroidRuntime(3529):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
09-15 20:33:49.697: E/AndroidRuntime(3529):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-15 20:33:49.697: E/AndroidRuntime(3529): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #81: Error inflating class fragment
09-15 20:33:49.697: E/AndroidRuntime(3529):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:587)
09-15 20:33:49.697: E/AndroidRuntime(3529):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
09-15 20:33:49.697: E/AndroidRuntime(3529):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
09-15 20:33:49.697: E/AndroidRuntime(3529):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
09-15 20:33:49.697: E/AndroidRuntime(3529):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
09-15 20:33:49.697: E/AndroidRuntime(3529):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
09-15 20:33:49.697: E/AndroidRuntime(3529):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:209)
09-15 20:33:49.697: E/AndroidRuntime(3529):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
09-15 20:33:49.697: E/AndroidRuntime(3529):     at org.linphone.LinphoneActivity.onCreate(LinphoneActivity.java:151)
09-15 20:33:49.697: E/AndroidRuntime(3529):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-15 20:33:49.697: E/AndroidRuntime(3529):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
09-15 20:33:49.697: E/AndroidRuntime(3529):     ... 11 more
09-15 20:33:49.697: E/AndroidRuntime(3529): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView
09-15 20:33:49.697: E/AndroidRuntime(3529):     at org.linphone.StatusFragment.onCreateView(StatusFragment.java:80)
09-15 20:33:49.697: E/AndroidRuntime(3529):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:846)
09-15 20:33:49.697: E/AndroidRuntime(3529):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1061)
09-15 20:33:49.697: E/AndroidRuntime(3529):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1160)
09-15 20:33:49.697: E/AndroidRuntime(3529):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:272)
09-15 20:33:49.697: E/AndroidRuntime(3529):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
09-15 20:33:49.697: E/AndroidRuntime(3529):     ... 21 more
```

Where I can take some info about what I am doing wrong?

**UPDATE 1**

line 80 in StatusFragment.java

```
statusText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.statusText);
```

And it's really TextView. Moreover I even don't touch that files.

To **Beginner**:

You can take code from git:

```
git clone git://git.linphone.org/linphone-android.git
```

if you want whole project, ready to build, use `--recursive` tag.

Comment: Possible that your resource ids are out of sync. Try cleaning and rebuilding the project.

Comment: What's in StatusFragment.java line 80?

Comment: Can you post some code

Comment: Logcat clearly show that there is an error in  `StatusFragment.java`, line 80. So if you you kindly post that `StatusFragment.java` file, it would be a lot easier to help you solve your problem.

Comment: @user2282470 plz help trying make build but no luck when i import ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18826876/linphone-android-how-to-import-the-library-project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Project->Clean in Eclipse, let it finish then run your application again, everything will work.

Eclipse caches your resource IDs based on the order of your views in the layout. If you change that around it is possible to get a classcastexception. Cleaning your project forces Eclipse to re-cache all your IDs properly.

Comment: I changing project on one machine and build it on another. To building I use existing Makefile. Which files I must replace to clear cache on build-machine?

Comment: plz help me out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18826876/linphone-android-how-to-import-the-library-project .. not able to import